# Checking millions of MySQL rows in Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have a Python program that downloads a text file of over 100 million unique values and follows the following logic:

1. If the value already exists in the table, update the entry's `last_seen` date (`SELECT id WHERE <col> = <value>;`)
2. If the value does not exist in the table, insert the value into the table

I queue up entries that need to be added and then insert them in a bulk statement after a few hundred have been gathered.

Currently, the program takes over 24 hours to run. I've created an index on the column that stores the values.

I'm currently using the MySQLdb.

It seems that checking for value existence is taking the lion's share of the runtime. What avenues can I pursue to make this faster?

Thank you.

Comment: We can help you better if you post some code.

Comment: MySQL is your bottleneck. What have you tried already regarding finding the data? You can perhaps do where <col> in (<value>, <value>, <value>, ....). where each <value> is a chunk of your unique values. That may speed things up

Comment: Is your data purely numerical?

Comment: If I were you I would use another database, like SolR or ElasticSearch, to store your data.

Comment: @Anushka--x the data is alphanumeric

Comment: @JulienCochennec I will check those both out thank you

Comment: @skarchmit since everything is alphanumeric lower-case I was thinking about creating a first character column, but I wasn't sure if that was something that really made sense given that I'm not very familiar with the inner-workings of MySQL

Comment: @CJB, You don't necessarily have to create the first character column, you can do where <col> ***like*** <character + '%'>

Answer (score 1):

You could try loading the values into a set, so you can do the lookups without fetching from the database every time.  Assuming that the table is not being updated by anyone else, and that you have sufficient memory.

```
# Let's assume you have a function runquery, that executes the 
# provided statement and returns a collection of values as strings.

existing_values = set(runquery('SELECT DISTINCT value FROM table'))

with open('big_file.txt') as f:
    inserts = []
    updates = []
    for line in f:
        value = line.strip()
        if value in existing_values:
            updates.append(value)
        else:
            existing_values.add(value)
            inserts.append(value)
        if len(inserts) > THRESHOLD or len(updates) > THRESHOLD:
            # Do bulk updates and clear inserts and updates
```